# How can we use ActivityCompat in place of Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-support-library

I read that we should use Activitycompat instead of Activity but when I'm extending ActivityCompat instead of Activity setContentView is unresolved along with onCreate, how can i use ActivityCompat, and in general how can I use support library feature

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityCompat {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to in your comments on the answers below?

Comment: @MikeM. I made it myself, I tried with ActivityCompat

Comment: I'm talking about your comments below - "...in documentation its clearly mentioned that we should use ActivityCompat not AppCompatActivity". Which documentation? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of ActivityCompact use AppCompatActivity
it will import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
I wrote simple example for you...

```
public class LockAdsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lock_ads);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        showMessage("I am Clicked man");
    }

    private void showMessage(String s) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: why is that because in documentation its clearly mentioned that we should use ActivityCompat not AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 1):

Try to extend from **AppCompatActivity** instead.

Comment: why is that because in documentation its clearly mentioned that we should use ActivityCompat not AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

Change `ActivityCompat` to `AppCompatActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }
}
```